# Button within div not allowing modal to open properly

Tags: javascript, html

A modal is being triggered when the div is clicked but since there is a button within the div, the button gets clicked instead of the modal opening. How can i disable the button functionality and have the modal open?

```
<div class="pic-info" data-remodal-target="modal">
   <button class="like-picture"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: is there an event-listener set on that button? shall that button do anything (other than the div)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any functionality on the button, why not just replace it with a `<span>`?

Try this and see if it works:

```
<div class="pic-info" data-remodal-target="modal">
   <span class="like-picture"></span>
</div>
```